# Base64-Encoded EC Private Key String to PrivateKey

Tags: android

I am trying to convert my private key string to a `PrivateKey` object in my Android application. I have read a lot of posts on StackOverflow about this topic, but I just can solve my issue.

I am using the following function to convert my key:

```
String privateKey = "MIGkAgEBBDCAHpFQ62QnGCEvYh/pE9QmR1C9aLcDItRbslbmhen/h1tt8AyMhskeenT+rAyyPhGgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQLW5ZJePZzMIPAxMtZXkEWbDF0zo9f2n4+T1h/2sh/fviblc/VTyrv10GEtIi5qiOy85Pf1RRw8lE5IPUWpgu553SteKigiKLUPeNpbqmYZUkWGh3MLfVzLmx85ii2vMU=";

@Nullable
private static PrivateKey getKey(String key) {
    try {
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(byteKey));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

According to [ASN.1 JavaScript decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGkAgEBBDCAHpFQ62QnGCEvYh_pE9QmR1C9aLcDItRbslbmhen_h1tt8AyMhskeenT-rAyyPhGgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQLW5ZJePZzMIPAxMtZXkEWbDF0zo9f2n4-T1h_2sh_fviblc_VTyrv10GEtIi5qiOy85Pf1RRw8lE5IPUWpgu553SteKigiKLUPeNpbqmYZUkWGh3MLfVzLmx85ii2vMU), I do have a valid private key.

Nonetheless, `getKey()` always fails with the following exception:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

I cannot make sense of this error message. Even after a lot of googling. Does anybody know, what I am doing wrong? Am I using the wrong key spec (though many of the answers here suggest the use of `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec()`.

The private key you see in the code above was generated by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) using an ES384 algorithm.